# How do I autocomplete a tag or element in Visual Studio while typing?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, canvas, hotkeys

If I have an element in XAML, that I want to be
`<canvas></canvas>`, how do I autocomplete this without typing it all out? I ran into this issue trying to type tags for the elements and getting stuck part way through knowing that Visual Studio might autocomplete the elements or tags I want to code.

For example I type:
`<canvas>` add a few attributes and want to complete element and go to the next line. How is that done?

Do I need a Visual Studio Extension like Web Essentials to do this?

Comment: visual studio also provide autocomplete tag on Tab or enter press.

Comment: The problem I have is with the attribute, once I type the value for the attribute and press tab it adds space but does not move out of the quotes. Like,  type(the double quotes are autocompleted before typing 100)
`<canvas Height="100"` then hit tab becomes `<canvas Height="100  "`

Comment: What version of studio are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing `<canvas` and few letters afterwards a dropdown or autocomplete will appear as part of Visual Studio's intellisense, press tab to autocomplete what intellisense decides is the best next thing you intend to type. There are tools online such as web essentials for Visual Studio that will allow someone to do things with tags and elements based on something like the asterisk symbol similar to rules in math that would allow someone to generate more than one tag for example. Visit the link for a reference: http://vswebessentials.com/

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio doesn't support auto completion for string literals.
You'll have to escape the quotes by moving the cursor.
Pressing Tab or typing the closing " yourself only makes it a mess.

> The IntelliSense options may not work as you expect in certain cases.
>   ...
>   **The cursor is in a string literal.**   You can't use IntelliSense if the
>   cursor is in the quotation marks around a string literal.
>   *Source:
>   [Troubleshooting IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx#Anchor_5)*

Although I have to add to this that in some languages IntelliSense does still give limited suggestions within the quotes. But escaping from auto-created quotes and brackets is a hassle.

---

An option: With some languages you can disable auto-completion for quotes in the options.
For example: (VS 2015)

- XAML: Miscellaneous: Auto Insert Attribute quotes
  Only the opening quote is added. You can close the literal yourself and keep typing.
- HTML: Advanced: Completion: Insert attribute value quotes
  No quotes will be added, you'll have to create both yourself.